# Can I change the current shell directory from a PHP script? If so, how?

Tags: php, shell, command-line-interface

I'm working on some PHP cli tools for MediaWiki and I want to be able to cd into a directory of the wiki, from the shell. Can I do that from PHP? If not, is it possible to wrap the entire thing into something else that is capable of doing this?

For example:

```
~$ mewsh @coin cd
```

Should take me the appropriate directory where coinwiki is located.  `chdir` is not sufficient as this will not change the directory after the PHP script is finished.

Comment: See here: [php.net/chdir](http://php.net/chdir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a matter of whether or not you can do it from php – you can't do it from any *spawned* process. A spawned process is a new process (created usually with [fork](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) and [exec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html)). Changes to the working directory of the new process cannot affect the working directory of the parent process.

That said, if you want to get crazy you can: Here's a php script that chdirs to the parent directory and then replaces itself with bash. It can't change the directory of the parent process, but it can start a *new* shell with a new directory.

```
<?php
chdir('..'); // Chdir to the parent directory in this php process.
pnctl_exec('/bin/bash'); /* Execute '/bin/bash' in the current process space.
  This is oversimplified in many ways
  – including that I didn't pass any arguments to the shell. */
```

For further hackery, if you're completely in control of how this script is invoked, you can `exec` it and replace the current shell with the new one.

```
~ $ exec php chdir.php
/Users $
```

But if you intend to share this script with someone you shouldn't have these expectations – it's much saner to manage the working directory *only* within your own program.